# Hint for problem including function of random variable?

Tags: self-study, distributions, variance

If $Y=\frac{\ln(U_1)}{\ln(U_1)+\ln(1-U_2)}$ where $U_1,U_2$ are independent $U(0,1)$ random variables, then variance of Y equals.

I usually use Jenson's inequality to underestimate or overestimate expectations of function of random variables (of any distribution ) but this is something different here the question is asking for the equality of variance how to do such questions thanks. Please suggest tags if they are not proper.

Comment: Hint: $-\ln(U_1)$ and $-\ln(1-U_2)$ are _independent_ exponential random variables with parameter $1$.

Comment: @Dilip's hint is good: it immediately shows that $1/Y-1$ has an $F(2,2)$ distribution and you can go on from there. But this one is easily solved using first principles: for any number $y\in(0,1)$, just compute $$\Pr(Y\le y) = \Pr(\log(U_1)\le y(\log(U_1)+\log(1-U_2)))=\Pr(U_1^{1/y-1}\le 1-U_2)$$ directly by integrating the $U_i$.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate please share some link where I can read it how $\ln(U_1)\ \ln(1-U_1)$ is a independent exponential random variables I am not getting this hint.

Comment: @Abomm It's $- \log(U_1)$ and $- \log(1 - U_2)$ that are independent exponential random variables.  All you need to do is see that $P(- \log(U) > t) = e^{-t}$ when $U \sim$ uniform$(0, 1)$.